# Command to not to kill hostages

Tags: counter-strike

Is there any command in CS 1.6 so that hostages (like in italy map) won't be get killed by either Ts or CTs?

Comment: Do you mean console command or a radio command? Oh, and for both questions the answer is `NO`

Comment: or do you want to mod hostages to have inf health?

Comment: @novarg radio command? never heard about it. at ratchet that also works

Answer (score 1):

There is no command to prevent hostages from being killed. Additionally, bots usually don't kill hostages.